# Calculating percentage of certain point type over rest inside grid using QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I have a layer of polygons which represent types of uses for a city, let's name it `USES_POLYGONS`. Think of a street: every building will have N number of polygons and each polygon will have a colour depending on its use (Restaurants, Clothing, Supermarket... a `Type` field).

I also have this same layer, same attributes, but as centroid and randomized point layers: `USES_POINTS`.

Along with the previous ones, I have a simple grid layer on top of my zone.

The goal is to colour the grid with a gradient scale depending on the uses of the polygons or the points inside each style. For example, let's say I want to measure the proportion of Restaurants over the rest of uses from 'Type', so the end result would be the grid coloured using any colour scale to depict intensity, being the most intense those tiles in which Restaurants have the biggest value over the rest.

Let's say there are 3 tiles:

Tile 1 has 2 polygons/points, 1 Restaurant and 1 Clothing;
Tile 2 has 3 polygons/points, 3 Restaurants
Tile 3 has 5 polygons/points, 1 Clothing, 1 Supermarket, 3 Empty Business.

Tile 2 will be the most intense coloured (100% of polygons/points are Restaurants); Tile 3 will be the least intense coloured (0% of polygons/points are Restaurants), and Tile 1 will have an in-between colour intensity (50% of Restaurants).

Any approach to do this?

My tries so far have led me to get how many points of each individual use are in the tiles, so I get the colour gradient depending on **how many points of a single use are inside a tile**, not depending on the rest of uses, and what I want to know is the relation between uses inside each tile: % of Restaurants over the rest of uses inside a tile; % of Clothing stores over Retail, Supermarkets and Residences inside a tile; % of Franchises over Non-Franchises inside a tile...)

Here are a couple images:

1. Image depicting intensity of uses for the type Restaurant alone
   [image: Image depicting intensity of uses for the type Restaurant alone]
2. Map depicting the Grid layer and the USES_POLYGONS layer
   [image: Map depicting the Grid layer and the USES_POLYGONS layer]

Comment: Did you try the ["Overlap analysis"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#overlap-analysis) tool ?

Comment: Please do not include chit chat like greetings and statements of appreciation within your posts.

Answer (score -1):

I reply here because I can not comment on my question. I tried using the Vector overlay tool, however what I get is the % of space taken up by each polygon in USES_POLYGONS. This data is nice to have, however it's not what I'm after since I want to know the percentage of each use inside a tile.

I have found a workaround for it: using intersect with my layer and my grid layer I can create a new layer with the data I want to analyse. The new intersected layer keeps the IDs of each tile of the grid, so I can treat those IDs as tiles and calculate % using conditions and filters.

Comment: It is important to not lose your connection details. Creating multiple accounts and posting answers as edits to the original question makes a mess of our database. Please search on how to merge multiple accounts within StackExchange and follow the procedure to repair this situation.

Comment: It appears as if the first part of your post is a comment and the second part of your post is an answer. Could you please clarify? Also, as @Vince pointed out, you cannot have duplicate accounts, so please remove on of them.